# Docstring at End

Tags: python, python-3.x, comments, docstring

I have written a simple code in Python . I read that if we write docstring at the end of code , then it is printed as usual. My code is

```
a = 'good'
b=  "boy"
print(a+ b)

"""
this will be a good example
"""
```

The output is

```
goodboy
```

However I suppose the output should be

```
goodboy
this will be a good example
```

I am unable to understand what is wrong here. Can anyone please tell me where I have made a mistake ?

Comment: When you are running a code nothing will be usually printed unless you put it inside a `print` statement

Comment: "I read that if we write docstring at the end of code , then it is printed as usual." — Read where?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a string for python:

"""
this will be a good example
"""

Try it like this:

```
a = 'good'
b=  "boy"
c = """
this will be a good example
"""
print(a + b + c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that? Creating a multiline string without assigning to anything is a valid statement in python, and is indeed used to create docstrings, but they are not supposed to be printed every time you run.

```
>>> def sample():
...     '''Sample doc'''
... 
>>> sample.__doc__
'Sample doc'
```

Also notice that this is useful to stub a function: instead of using `pass` you can document what the function is doing, which is a good practice to follow.